# Zend_Form Validator Syntax Error -- Does this violate php class rules?

Tags: php, zend-framework, class

I am creating a custom validator in Zend framework.

```
const MSG_MINIMUM = 'msgMinimum';
const MSG_MAXIMUM = 'msgMaximum';
const MSG_NUMERIC = 'msgNumeric';

protected $_config = null;
protected $_min = 0;
protected $_max = 0;

protected $_messageTemplates = array(
  self::MSG_MINIMUM => "You must have at least ".$this->_min." selected",
  self::MSG_MAXIMUM => "Too many, ".$this->_max." selected",
  self::MSG_NUMERIC => "'%value%' is not a valid number"
);

public function __construct(Zend_Config $config)
{
  $this->_config = $config;
  $this->_min = $this->_config->limit->orderMin;
  $this->_max = $this->_config->limit->orderMax;
}
```

Any idea why this line is a syntax error?

```
self::MSG_MINIMUM => "You must have at least ".$this->_min." selected",
```

I have a feeling I am breaking class rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property declarations in the body of the class cannot contain expressions. They must be static values only. You would have to initialise `$_messageTemplates` in the constructor.

Like this:

```
// ...

protected $_messageTemplates;

public function __construct(Zend_Config $config)
{

  // ...

  $this->_messageTemplates = array (
    self::MSG_MINIMUM => "You must have at least ".$this->_min." selected",
    self::MSG_MAXIMUM => "Too many, ".$this->_max." selected",
    self::MSG_NUMERIC => "'%value%' is not a valid number"
  );

}
```